# Can I just display the tag_name from my MonkeyLearn model?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, monkeylearn

Hi is there a way I can display just the tag_name using MonkeyLearn instead of a full text?
Here is the code

```
from monkeylearn import MonkeyLearn
ml = MonkeyLearn('xxxx')
classifier = ['text']
model_id = 'xxxx'
response = ml.classifiers.classify(model_id, data)
print(response.body)
```

I have tried using print(response.classifications) but I get and error saying that

```
'MonkeyLearnResponse' object has no attribute 'classifications'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely due to the wrong use of the library. I believe it's on this -`ml.classifiers.classify(model_id, data)` line where it doesn't return the correct object.

Sample code from the [docs](https://github.com/monkeylearn/monkeylearn-python#auto-batching)

```
from monkeylearn.exceptions import PlanQueryLimitError

data = ['Text to classify'] * 300
batch_size = 200

try:
    response = ml.classifiers.classify('[MODEL_ID]', data, batch_size=batch_size)
except PlanQueryLimitError as e:
```

As you can see, try to pass your `model_id` as an array value rather than a string and ensure your `data` variable is correct.